# CEWP to set Infopath field value not working

Tags: 2010, javascript, infopath, cewp

I have an infopath form web part on my web page along with a CEWP. I'm using javascript in my CEWP to set a field on my Infopath form to some value when a button is clicked. For some reason I can't get the Infopath field to update.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function filter()
{       document.getElementById("#ctl00_m_g_01d631bf_e556_4975_acbb_226c880bfd44_FormControl0_V1_I1_E1").Value= "TestValue";
}
    </script>
    <button onclick="setTimeout(filter,3000);" type="submit">Click</button>
```

The #ctl00_m_g_01d631bf_e556_4975_acbb_226c880bfd44_FormControl0_V1_I1_E1 is the ID of my text field.

Comment: Can you post the JavaScript Code?

Comment: Just edited my original post with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you used a # in the getelementbyid where it should not be.

Try to remove the #.

Documentation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp)